# About notation of function

Tags: functions, notation

Suppose I have a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. I am writing this:

> $f$ is a nice function.

Is this sentence the same as the sentence

> $t \mapsto f(t)$ is a nice function.

In other words, is the notation $f$ the same as the notation $t \mapsto f(t)$?

Comment: The _notation_ is different, the _denotation_ is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the only difference between those two statements is that you're specifying $t$ as the argument of the function. This allows you to say things like "there is a value of $t$ such that..." or "when $t=\frac{a+b}{2}$, we have...", which might be confusing if you had not specified that the function $f$ acts on $t$.

Similarly, if you mention that "$t\mapsto f(t)$ is a nice function", it would be doubly confusing if you started talking about how the function behaves over different values of $x$.

Comment: What about, "$f(t)$ is a nice function"?  Perhaps this isn't valid because $f(t)$ is actually just an element in the range of $f$?

Comment: That's exactly right.  However, $f(t)$ is used often enough as shorthand for $t \mapsto f(t)$ that you would probably be understood nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has the same meaning.

**Explanation:**
The notation
$$f : t\mapsto ...$$
is for denoting the mapping rule of $f$. However, the rule
$$f : t\mapsto f(t)$$
is void, so
$$\text{"}f : t\mapsto f(t)\text{"}$$
is telling us nothing more than
$$\text{"}f\text{ is a function".}$$